# Dynamically update combobox based on user selection

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am not sure how postback works on WinForms, but I want to allow the `ComboBox` to update based on the user selection.

Currently when I change the selection of my first `ComboBox`, it doesn't change the items in the second dropdown. (only showing the first item by default)

In what ways can O alter this?

Code to what I have:

```
public ContentUploader()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ... re.OverallID = 1", conString))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            sections_drp.ValueMember = "ID";
            sections_drp.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
            sections_drp.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
    sections_drp.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, e) => FillFirstChildren();
}
public void FillFirstChildren()
{
    firstChild_drp.Items.Add("Select Item");
    firstChild_drp.SelectedIndex = 0;
    string sectionId = sections_drp.SelectedValue.ToString();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ... em.ItemID = ("+ sectionId +")", conString))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            firstChild_drp.ValueMember = "ID";
            firstChild_drp.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
            firstChild_drp.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
    FillSecondChildren();
}
```

Comment: Use selected_index_change event of the first combo to fill the second

Comment: @kostasch. and if i have multiple combos i would fill each one on the previous one's selected_index_change event?

Comment: You just answer your question :)

Comment: @Masriyah exactly, each combo box will have a different change_event handler

Comment: Handle `SelectedIndexChanged` of each Combo box

Comment: @kostasch. i updated my post with the answer below but it doesn't seem to be doing what it should do. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Winforms` does not contain a post back.  You will need to tie to the `SelectedIndexChanged` (or `Item` or `Value`) event to filter your second dropdown.

Example:

```
    public void FillFirstChildren()
    {
        //Your Fill Logic Here
        ...

        //Call FillSecondChildren on selection change
        firstChild_drop.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, e) => FillSecondChildren();
    }
```

Comment: do i place `firstChild_drop.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, e) => FillSecondChildren();` inside the `using` statement and after `firstChild_drp.DataSource=dt`?

Comment: At the very end of that method.